# synchronized or not in java setField method

Tags: java, synchronized

In thre product env, we found duplicate primary key error. IdGenerator.generateId()  was thread-safe, so i suspected method setId() isn't synchronized, but i can't figure out the principle reason. somewhat like this:
bill.setId(IdGenerator.generateId()) --> {step1:Long id=IdGenerator.generateId(); step２:　bill.setId(id); }；Thus, multi threads in step2 share the same value in step1.

```
   public long saveBill(Bill bill) throws Exception {
    //IdGenerator.generateId() was an synchronized method
    bill.setId(IdGenerator.generateId());
    return billDao.saveBill(bill);
    }
```

Comment: IMHO the whole `saveBill` should be atomic.

Comment: How are you generating Id?

Comment: refer to snowflake, i think   bill.setId()  was not thread-safe, cause two threads use the same id.

Comment: I don't think there's a concurrency problem in `saveBill`. Assuming that `id` is the primary key of `Bill`, and problem would be because either: `generateId()` is returning duplicates; `bill` is shared between threads; or `saveBill()` has a bug.

Comment: Yes, id is the primary key of Bill. the algorithm of generateId()  has been verfied several months, which is reliable. each thread creates their own bill object, and then pass to the method.